High Current, High Voltage DC Load Switch using NMOSFETs
I am designing a Power Monitoring and Protection board that is going to sit in between a 5-Series (~70V) Lead Acid Battery and a load. This board has a Energy Monitoring IC from TI - INA237AQDGSRQ1 and a STM32F091C8Tx as the MCU. The load current will be 50A continuous and 80A peak. The idea is to get the data from INA237 and switch 4/5 parallel MOSFETs when any protection condition is hit. The board needs to protect against:

Over voltage during charge.
Under voltage during discharge.
Overcurrent in charge.
Overcurrent in discharge.

So essentially this board will function as a BMS. The MOSFETs are going to be turned on or off only when a protection event will occur. Hence this is not a high speed switching application. So I cannot be using ICs designed for PWM application as I will be switching the MOSFETs statically.
Here are the approaches I have considered so far and my thoughts on the same. (Please correct me if I am wrong):

Use a ASIC BMS IC to handle the protection and switching.


This is not possible because such an IC doesn't exist.


Using a gate driver IC such as UCC2751x to drive the MOSFETSs in lowside.


The catch here is, since the protection is on low side, let's say the batteries went into undervoltage and the MCU switches the MOSFETs off. Now since the system ground is floating, the voltage reported by INA237 will be wrong and hence I will have no data using which I will be able to turn the MOSFETs back on. For ex, I will never be able to detect a charger getting connected and turn the MOSFETs on.


Using NMOS on high side and using an appropriate gate driver to switch the MOSFETs.


Here, since the MOSFETs are on the high side, even if I switch the MOSFETs off, INA237 will still be able to measure the voltage or I can have a simple voltage divider that connects to the MCU to measure the voltage on terminals. With this I can turn the MOSFETs back on when I detect a charger being connected, for example.

So essentially I think I need a high side switch and a suitable gate driver. I have identified IRS10752LPBF as a high side gate driver that is operational upto 100V which is higher than my system voltage.
Now if I wire up the Pin (3) IN of this gate driver to my MCU's GPIO and connect 4/5 NMOS parallel as shown in the application diagram of the IC, will everything work as intended? I think I am missing something. I have reading about this online and I notice mention of key words like "Charge Pump" etc.
I have not considered dual channel H Bridge Gate Driver ICs which will have integrated charge pump because I am trying control only one channel of MOSFETs. If ignoring the low side driver and just implementing the high side is my best bet, please advise.
Edit: Please see the block diagram.

So here when the MOSFET is open and I connect a charger on Pack+ and Pack-, I need a way to measure the voltage or atleast know there is a change in the potential. Maybe I just need a optocoupler or something similar?

Welcome! Please provide a schematic or block diagram of what you have. Can you sense current on the low side but switch on high side?

No, the sense resistor is also placed on the high side as shown in Fig 8-2 in the datasheet of INA2373 [link] https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina237.pdf

Sure, but what prevents you from a low side sense approach? Please update your question with a schematic or block diagram.

Like you said, for current sensing high side or low side doesn't matter. But my issue is with switching. In the sensing side, my concern is not current sensing but voltage because if I lose the reference, then I cannot sense the voltage anymore. I will add a diagram soon.

With sensing on low side and high side switching, you won't loose any reference.

Yes, but I am trying to understand how to do the high side switching. Want to ensure my point (3) will work.

You will need a charge pump or DC-DC converter to generate gate voltage above your Vbus+. Plenty of examples if you search around.

Not a complete answer because there are details missing from the question, but here are some big gaps to address.

For parallel FETs, you'll need a gate driver for each one in order to prevent gate oscillations and other interactions between the FETs.

The voltage for VB (as referenced on the mentioned driver) needs to be higher than the voltage to be controlled, by more than the Vth of the FET.  Usually about 10-15V, but that is FET dependent.

You could switch to PFETs instead of NFETs, with the trade that the power dissipation will be a little higher, but the drive circuit can be easier to design. (reference to #1 & #2)



Hello,

I can prevent gate oscillations by simply adding a ~50E gate resistor for each of the MOSFET in parallel.
Yes, this is what drivers that have integrated charge pump fixes, right?
Since the load is going to be mostly ON, PFET cannot be considered. They have higher switching losses AND higher cost as well.


@AbhijithVNarayan 1. Maybe. 2. Neither gate driver mentioned has built in charge pump. The IRS10752 can be bootstrapped, but that requires toggling, not just steady state. Think about how a charge pump works.

Okay, thank you kind sir. Do you have any insights on high side driver FET IC that has integrated charge pump?
